# How to get a character from an extended ascii number

Tags: string, actionscript, extended-ascii

The ascii code charts say that a "ü" is at 129 (decimal). 
But when I do a trace("ü".charCodeAt(0)) ... the answer I get is 252 - which is obviously wrong.
Seems that String.charCodeAt() only works for 0-127.
How do you convert between char and charcode values for ranges 128-255?

Comment: ASCII doesn't exist beyond 127. There are loads of standards to encode the high bit.

Comment: Could you provide just a simple example in actionscript. I assume it's one or two lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is more than one character set that some call "extended ASCII," there isn't much meaning to the term. ASCII itself is rarely used.

As you've found, it is important to know which character set and encoding you are using. Although some libraries are flexible in adapting to "the platform default," programs generally aren't  written that way and, if they read or write data across systems, the flexibility is moot.

There is no text but encoded text. When you pass someone text, you have data loss if you don't also give the encoding as metadata.

ActionScript strings are sequences of Unicode/UTF-16 code units. See [charCodeAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#charCodeAt()). Unlike most character sets, Unicode has several encodings; UTF-16 being two of them. (Integers are stored big endian or little endian and so is a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 means either UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE, depending the platform, but through the use of a BOM in the string, the data itself can specify the byte order and indicate which Unicode encoding is used.)

ü is stored as one UTF-16 code unit with the value of 252. See [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS' (U+00FC)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fc/index.htm) or [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt).